# 17 year old US Citizen traveling to Canada

Tags: canada, us-citizens, minors

I'll be traveling to Canada while I'm 17 (20 days from being 18) for a business conference and had questions about the page regarding ["Minor children travelling to  Canada"](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/minor-children-travelling-canada.html).

I currently don't live with my parents making it hard to get a consent form, but I noticed it says "Minors who try to enter Canada without the proper documents, or who are with adults other than their parents or legal guardian(s), will be checked more closely." implying that you don't actually need this form.

I'm wondering what risk there is if I travel to Canada alone with only my valid US Passport and no forms at all. Maybe someone with experience might have an idea.

Comment: Do you in fact have your parents' consent to travel to Canada?  If so, a phone call or even the suggestion of one might be enough.

Comment: @phoog of course, as I said this is a legitimate business conference. Do you mean I should offer the border agent to call my parent? I thought about this but how do they know I don't just have my friend on the other line, etc.

Comment: The obvious question is: Why don't you live with your parents? The answer to that might just resolve the whole situation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton because I am in another state for an internship.

Comment: Hmm. If you already live and work on your own then I don't really expect you'll have much of a problem at the border. This could still use a look from someone with more experience or authoritative references, though.

Comment: I asked because you said you don't live with your parents, and it wasn't otherwise clear whether you had a good relationship with them.  Border officers are well enough trained in interrogation that they probably have pretty good confidence that they'd be able to expose a friend on the other end of the line.  But couldn't they just mail you a (preferably notarized) consent letter?

Comment: @phoog I suppose they could mail me one, it just seems like an unnecessary hassle for both of us. I think it would be helpful to learn in general too what happens when you only have a passport and you're a minor.

Comment: Yes it would certainly be a hassle.  I frankly doubt you'll have a problem without it.  The warnings about traveling with adults other than your parents, of course, are mostly concerned with abduction and human trafficking.  The latter could also be a concern for children traveling by themselves.  So you might get a few extra questions.  I doubt it would go farther than that, especially given your age.